Where are Perl arrays @0, @9999 documented?
$ perl -wle 'my @388=0..2;'
Can't use global @388 in "my" at -e line 1, near "my @388"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
$ perl -wle '@388=0..2;'
$

Where can I learn more about Perl's mysterious @0, ..., @9999, etc.?

These are "special identifiers" of the first type mentioned in perldata:

[...] special identifiers don't follow the above rules; For the
most part, all of the identifiers in this category have a special
meaning given by Perl. Because they have special parsing rules, these
generally can't be fully-qualified. They come in six forms (but don't
use forms 5 and 6):

A sigil, followed solely by digits matching \p{POSIX_Digit}, like
$0, $1, or $10000.


All of $0, @0, and %0 would fall under this type of identifier, but $0a, @0a, and %0a would not and would generate a syntax error if you tried to use them.
Since these names start with a digit, they are furthermore always scoped to the main package and can't be localised with my.  This is mentioned in the perlvar manual:

Perl identifiers that begin with digits or punctuation characters are
exempt from the effects of the package declaration and are always
forced to be in package main; they are also exempt from strict 'vars' errors.

The scalar numeric variables ($0, $1, $2, ...) are reserved and documented. The variable $0 holds the name of the current program, while the others are read-only and hold the captured bits from the most recent regular expression match.
The array and hash variables with the same names are not used by Perl in any documented way (apart from having "a special
meaning" as mentioned above), and could potentially be used by someone who wanted to write obfuscated Perl code.
